# How to divide data from the series in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to process data from a .csv file to:

1. **Divide** the data coming in by 10, e.g., **588 => 58.8**
2. **Remove** outliers from the data or to change to zero, e.g., **8888 => 0**

Here is my javascript, I appreciate the help!!

```
$.get('http://www.geoinc.org/Dropbox/geo/sites/GC_ROOM/charts/hassayampa.csv', function(data)
   {
      // Split the lines
      var lines = data.split('\n');
      var i = 0;
      var csvData = [];



      // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
      $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line)
      {
         csvData[i] = line.split(',');

         i = i + 1;

      });


      var columns = csvData[0];

      var categories = [], series = [];


      for(var colIndex=0,len=columns.length; colIndex<len; colIndex++)
      {
         //first row data as series's name
         var seriesItem=
         {
            data:[],
            name:csvData[0][colIndex]
         };

         for(var rowIndex=1,rowCnt=csvData.length; rowIndex<rowCnt; rowIndex++)
         {
            //first column data as categories,
            if (colIndex == 0)
            {
               categories.push(csvData[rowIndex][0]);
            }
            else if(parseFloat(csvData[rowIndex][colIndex])) // <-- here
            {
               seriesItem.data.push(parseFloat(csvData[rowIndex][colIndex])); 
            }
         };
         //except first column
         if(colIndex>0)series.push(seriesItem);
      }         



      // Create the chart
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
      {
         chart:
         {
            renderTo: 'test',
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x',
         },
         title: {
                text: 'Daily Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: HASSAYAMPA',
                x: -20
            },

         xAxis: 
         {
            categories: categories,
            labels:
            {
               step: 80,
            },
            tickWidth: 0
         },
         yAxis: 
         {
                    title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)'
                },
            //min: 0
         },
         tooltip:
         {
            formatter: function()
            {
               return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ this.x +': '+ this.y +'\xB0C';
            }
         },
         legend:
         {
            layout: 'vertical',
            //backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            //floating: true,
            align: 'left',
            //x: 100,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            //y: 70,
            borderWidth: 0
         },

         plotOptions:
         {
            area:
            {
               animation: false,
               stacking: 'normal',
               lineColor: '#666666',
               lineWidth: 1,
               marker:
               {
                  lineWidth: 1,
                  lineColor: '#666666'
               }
            }
         },
         series: series
      });

   });
```

Comment: What did you want `else if(parseFloat(csvData[rowIndex][colIndex])) // <-- here` to do? This isn't really a question as written. Is the Hightower stuff part of your issue? What specifically do you need help doing?

Comment: I want to divide the values from the data by ten. So **588** => **58.5**, because these are temperatures in Celsius, the raw data does not set a decimal point, so I have to manipulate the data in my script to it is interpreted as something that makes sense. @ruffin, thanks for your quick attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but I'll take a shot at it...

First things first, this snippet of code is not sound. It'll not only skip NaNs but 0s as well (which is valid numeric data):

```
else if(parseFloat(csvData[rowIndex][colIndex]))
{
    seriesItem.data.push(parseFloat(csvData[rowIndex][colIndex])); 
}
```

Instead I'd do:

```
//first column data as categories,
if (colIndex == 0)
{
   categories.push(csvData[rowIndex][0]);
}
else
{
    var fVal = parseFloat(csvData[rowIndex][colIndex]);
    if (!isNaN(fVal))
    {
        fVal = fVal / 10.0; //<-- here's the division!!
        seriesItem.data.push(fVal);
    }   
}
```

As far as how to exclude outliers, the big question there is how do *you want* to exclude outliers?  A simple min/max criteria?  Then just check that fVal is within those limits before seriesItem.data.push...

Comment: Thank you for your helped this helped a lot! I can deal with the outliers separately. Thanks again @mark